# Jackson @JsonBackReference annotated property

Tags: java, javafx, jackson

```
@JsonBackReference
ObjectProperty<MyObject> myObjectProperty = new SimpleObjectProperty();
```

When I use this code, Jackson still tries to recursively go through `myObjectProperty`. Jackson has support for Collections and some other types, but how can I add support for `ObjectProperty`?

I was considering subclassing `SimpleObjectProperty` and annotating `value` with `@JsonBackReference`, but I don't have access to `value` as it is `private`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to annotate the getter for `myObectProperty` with `@JsonBackReference`.